# Unable to iterate over scala list serialized with kryo

Tags: scala, serialization, singleton, akka, null

I have a Scala/Akka application that is storing serialized messages using Kryo, and then re-introducing them to the system on future runs. However, I am getting exceptions from Scala when trying to run a for comprehension over a list within the message.

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: head of empty list
    at scala.collection.immutable.Nil$.head(List.scala:422)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Nil$.head(List.scala:419)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:278)
    ...
```

Comment: As a note, I came across this when I was sure that the message was not coming from the kryo-serialized messages (as I thought there were none, that the persisted store was cleared at the beginning of tests). It was pretty hellish to work out until I finally figured out Kryo was involved - hopefully if someone else comes across this one, they might find the question and get a push towards Kryo, as it took me a while to get to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be caused by serializing data using Kryo without scala-specific serializers.

The issue is that Scala creates singleton objects such as `Nil` each time the JVM starts up, then uses identity to compare against them (as it's very quick to do so). Unfortunately, Kryo doesn't know the object is meant to be a singleton inherently, so when you deserialize, you get back a different instance of `Nil` (when scala assumes there is only one).

The solution to this is to ensure that Kryo deserializes these objects back to the correct representation for the current run, which can be achieved using a library like [chill](https://github.com/twitter/chill) (specifically the chill-scala serializers).